# flask app with factory - separate routes file

Tags: python, flask, routes, factory

I am trying to figure out the files structure of a flask app.
I've used flask-dotenv and the FLASK_APP is main.py

myapp/.flaskenv - specifies the FLASK_APP
myapp/main.py
myapp/app/**init**.py - has the create_app() function. This imports a db as well from db.py
myapp/app/db.py - the database related functions

I'd like to have all routes in a separate routes.py file (rather than within the create_app() method.
myapp/app/routes.py

I'd appreciate some help in finding how is it that I can link this routes.py in.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `blueprint` to organize and register your routes.

Essentially, you can have a folder structure like this:

```
app/ <-- your entire application folder
    auth/                               <-- blueprint package for /auth route
        __init__.py                     <-- blueprint creation
        routes.py                       <-- authentication routes
    profile/
        __init__.py                     <-- blueprint package for /profile route
        routes.py                       <-- profile routes
    __init__.py                         <-- ceate_app and blueprint registration
```

Under your routes package, for example in `auth` folder:

```
# app/auth/__init__.py
# this is initialize auth blueprint
from flask import Blueprint
bp = Blueprint('auth',__name__,)
from app.auth import routes
```

Then you can put all your `authentication` routes in `auth/routes.py`, but instead of using `app.route`, you need to use `bp.route` like this:

```py
# app/auth/routes.py
# this is where you can put all your authentication routes
from app.auth import bp
# notice here the route '/login' is actually prefixed with 'auth'
# because in the following code I added "url_prefix='/auth' " in the create_app() factory.
# the full routes will be 'auth/login' on your website.
@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    ....your login code...
```

Then in your `__init__.py` you can do this:

```py
# app/__init__.py
from app.auth import bp as auth_bp
from app.profile import bp as profile_bp
    
def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp,url_prefix='/auth')
    app.register_blueprint(profile_bp,url_prefix='/profile')
```

This way all routes to `yourdomain.com/auth/...` will be in `app/auth/routes.py` ; all routes to `yourdomain.com/profile/...` will be in your `app/profile/routes.py`.

Check this wonderful tutorial about Flask for more details:

[Flask mega tutorial by Miguel Grinberg](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure)

This specific part is about how you can better organize your application structure.

Comment: I see, thanks. Well actually I was trying to avoid using blueprints. This would be just a very simple test app on my own localhost. Is it possible without blueprint?